# How to make $S\otimes_R M$ into a left $S[G]$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

I have a basic question on tensor products which might have been asked before-sorry if this is the case.

Let $G$ be a finite group and $R\subset S$ any (unital) ring extension. Let $M$ be a finitely generated left $R[G]$-module. I form the tensor product $S\otimes_R M$ which is a left $S$-module.

> What is the standard way to make this into a left $S[G]$-module? Is it via the rule $(\sum_{g\in G}s_gg,x\otimes m)\mapsto \sum_{g\in G}(s_gx\otimes gm)$ on generators?

Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, that would be the way. (I just add that $R$ and $S$ must be commutative if you want this to make sense, or at least $R$).

Comment: Sorry for the silly question but isn''t $S$ an $(S,R)$-bimodule whether or not $R$ is commutative? Regards

Comment: No, indeed it makes sense, my "someone tried to take a tensor product over a non-commutative ring" radar just went off, but in this case it's okay. The fact that you very rarely see group algebras over non-commuative rings didn't help either. But there is no problem here ! :)